# Lipschitz Continuity of a Noisy Signal

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lipschitz-functions, random-functions

1-Let $(\mathcal{X},\|.\|_q)$ be a compact metrix space. Also let $f(\mathbf{x})=A\mathbf{x}$, $\forall \mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{X}$. Can, I define the Lipschitz continuity constraint on $f(.)$ w.r.t vector norms, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
\|f(\mathbf{x}_1)-f(\mathbf{x}_2)\|_p\leq L\|\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x_2}\|_q
\end{equation}

2 - Now, let $f(\mathbf{x})=A\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{n}$, where $\mathbf{n}$ be a bounded random noise. Can the same Lipschitz constraint be applied to this $f(.)$ as well? To the best of my knowledge, Lipschitz continuity constraint cant be applied to random signals.

Comment: Isn´t  $||f(x_1)-f(x_2)||_p=||Ax_1+n-(Ax_2+n)||_p=||Ax_1-Ax_2\underbrace{+n-n}_{=0}||_p\leq L||x_1-x_2||_q$??

Comment: For random noise, $f(x_1)$ Will have a different value of $n$ than $f(x_2). So the difference is not zero.

Comment: Ok, can You say how $A:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow \mathcal{X}$ (or  is it $A:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$ where $(\mathcal{Y},||.||_p)$ is another metric space) is exactly defined and how is $n$ defined? Does $n$  depend on some $\omega\in\Omega$ where $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ is a probability space and are You asking whether $||Ax_1+n(x_1,\omega_1)-(Ax_2+n(x_2,\omega_2)||_p\leq C||x_1-x_2||_q$ where $C=2\underbrace{\sup_{\omega\in\Omega}||n(.,\omega)||_p}_{<\infty}$?? or something like that?

Comment: Exactly yes. I am specifically curious to know that given this setup i.e., for some random bounded noise $n$ (following some probability distribution $P$); can Lipschitz continuity assumption still be assumed on $f(x)=y = Ax+n\in\mathcal{Y}$?

Comment: If I got it right I think the answer is positive: using the triangle inequality and the boundedness of $n:\mathcal{X}\times\Omega\rightarrow\mathcal{Y}$ on gets a new Lipschitz constant $L'=L2\sup_{(x,\omega)\in\mathcal{X}\times\Omega}||n(x,\omega)||_p$ assuming that $n$ is bounded over all of $\mathcal{X}\times\Omega$